# Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis, phpredis

I'am using Laravel queue.and I set up my .env file as follows.

```
QUEUE_DRIVER = database
QUEUE_CONNECTION = database
```

But I get this error.

```
Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled.
```

Can anyone explain that and fix this problem and give me the solution.
Do I really need redis? Because I do not want to use it.

Comment: What about your cache settings? Make sure to set that to database as well. It is possible not to use Redis.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Instead of commenting out Providers, why don't you install the PHP Redis Extension? Its a fast cache driver.

Comment: Are you trying to use Laravel Horizon? It only runs on redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all.
I solve this issue by adding this line in `.env` file

```
REDIS_CLIENT = predis
```

then run this command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: installing the package: composer require predis/predis worked as well, so run: composer require predis/predis

Answer (score 0):

It gives that error because the registered service provider uses config/database.php's redis config array to initialize redis (make connection).

If you remove/comment-out `Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,` from the `providers` array of `config/app.php` it won't initialize redis and won't give an error.

Edit: please be sure that none of the drivers of session, queue, cache etc didn't use `redis` after making that change.